# Javascript regex match using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying below code to get the output 1. But not able to get it.

```
var labhost = '0';
var podmaster_node = "evhlab65.ms.com";
var matchtxt = new RegExp('\w+\.ms\.com', "i");


if (podmaster_node.match(matchtxt)) {
    labhost = '1';
}

alert(labhost);
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly should the regex match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are escaping Regular Expression in `RegExp` constructor, you need to escape like this

```
var matchtxt = new RegExp('\\w+\\.ms\\.com', "i");
```

`\w+`, translates to `w+`. So you need to escape `\` with `\\`, which makes `\` as part of the regular expression.

```js
var labhost = '0';
var podmaster_node = "evhlab65.ms.com";
var matchtxt = new RegExp('\\w+\\.ms\\.com', "i");


if (podmaster_node.match(matchtxt)) {
  labhost = '1';
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = labhost;
```

```html
<div id="result" />
```

**Note:** The better way to do this would be to use Regular Expression literal, like this

```
var matchtxt = /\w+\.ms\.com/i;
```